# Select only start date in Date Range and Set +7 days for End (Bootstrap Date Range Picker)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am trying to have an event triggered when you click on the start date in the date range picker, I have tried a few ways and have this so far:
HTML:

```
 <input class="form-control pull-right" type="text" name="daterange" id="dateRangeP" >
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            locale: {
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
            }
        });

        $('input[name="daterange"]').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var startDate = $("#dateRangeP").data('daterangepicker').startDate._d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');

            var endDate = moment(startDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(7, 'days')._d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');

            $("#dateRangeP").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(startDate);
            $("#dateRangeP").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(endDate);
            debugger;
            $(this).val(startDate + '-' + endDate);
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

At the moment it works when you click outside the box but I need it for when I click on the start date. I have tried to use change the function to call below but it only works after the apply button is selected and both dates have been selected

```
$('#dateRangeP').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
alert ('hello');
```

});

I have done a lot of searching before posting here but cannot seem to find any guidance, some guidance would be greatly appreciated. If unclear please let me know.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/40cwdk7h/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ...
`dateLimit: { days: 7 }`

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        dateLimit: { days: 7 },
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY '
        },

    });

});
```

link https://jsfiddle.net/rLnycn80/1845/

Comment: Thanks @Sooriya what I was looking for at the time

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes, that function is only called when you clicked on apply button. 
For setting a dynamic end date at runtime used two datepicker instead of daterangepicker.
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/kartik_bhalala/2euar7d3/19/

Comment: Thanks, @Kartik so far for the help. Instead of showing it in two textboxes (I don't mind if the boxes are hidden) but show both dates after clicking one in the date range so the user is aware that it is only showing data for the next 7 days?

Comment: Yes, User is aware about that in that case you have to hide that end date textbox. You have to use end date in backend means hidden. Actually I made dynamically generated end date demo. You can use it according to your requirements.